# Complexification of Metric

Tags: linear-algebra, riemannian-geometry

If we have given an inner product space $(V,g)$, where $V$ is vector space and $g$ is inner product.  What will be corresponding bi-linear form $g'$ on $C\otimes V$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume $V$ is a real vector space. I'll write the inner product as $\langle, \rangle$. Now, there are (at least) two options for extending it to $\mathbb{C} \otimes V$:

**Option 1:** Make it $\mathbb{C}$-bilinear in both variables. That is, set 
$$\langle c_1 \otimes v_1, c_2 \otimes v_2 \rangle_{\mathbb{C}} = c_1 c_2 \langle v_1, v_2 \rangle$$

and extend linearly. Unfortunately, the result will not be positive-definite.

**Option 2:** Make it conjugate-linear in the first variable and linear in the second. That is, set
$$\langle c_1 \otimes v_1, c_2 \otimes v_2 \rangle_{\mathbb{C}} = \overline{c_1} c_2 \langle v_1, v_2 \rangle$$

and extend linearly. The result will be positive-definite.